# Jquery matcing array elements to create a calendar view

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a problem with creating a view which is consist of 3 different arrays. 
First array has resources, second array has dates and the third array has the data that i am trying to match with both resource and date. I am trying to have a view like matrice or calendar.

This is resources array;

```
resourceArray:[ {resourceId:"a", "name":"Test User"},
                { resourceId:"b", "name":"Test User2"},
                { resourceId:"c", "name":"Test User3"},
                { resourceId:"d", "name":"Test User4"},
                { resourceId:"e", "name":"Test User5"},
                { resourceId:"f", "name":"Test User6"}]
```

This is the data array;

```
   dataArray= [
      { "id": "1", "resourceId": "a", "start": "2018-10-02", "end": "2018-10-17", "title": "event 1" },
      { "id": "2", "resourceId": "b", "start": "2018-10-07", "end": "2018-10-07", "title": "event 2" },
      { "id": "3", "resourceId": "c", "start": "2018-10-06", "end": "2018-10-15", "title": "event 3" },
      { "id": "4", "resourceId": "d", "start": "2018-10-07", "end": "2018-10-21", "title": "event 4" },
      { "id": "5", "resourceId": "e", "start": "2018-10-07", "end": "2018-10-22", "title": "event 5" },
      { "id": "6", "resourceId": "f", "start": "2018-10-07", "end": "2018-10-10", "title": "event 6" },
      { "id": "7", "resourceId": "f", "start": "2018-10-11", "end": "2018-10-13", "title": "event 7" }
    ]
```

And the dates only has an array such as

```
var dates=["2018/11/01",...] goes like that.
```

In final i'd like to have a view like that;
[image]

What i have tried;

```
for (let q = 0; q < options.resources.length; q++) {
                const resourceElement = options.resources[q];

                for (var j = 0; j < dateArray.length; j++) {

                    var result=options.data.find(x=>moment(dateArray[j]).isBetween(moment(x.start).format('YYYY/MM/DD'),moment(x.end).format('YYYY/MM/DD'), null, '[]'));
                console.log(result);
                    var matcingResource = (result.resourceId == resourceElement.resourceId ? true : false);

                    if (result && matcingResource) {
                        var columnItemDiv = jQuery("<div>", {
                            "class": "kalender-calendarContainer-calendarColumnItem",
                            "eventID": result.id, "start": result.start, "end": result.end
                        }).append(result.title);

                        var column = columnDivsArray.find(x => x.resourceId === resourceElement.resourceId).calendarColumnDiv;
                        column.append(columnItemDiv);
                    }
                    else {

                        var column = columnDivsArray.find(x => x.resourceId === resourceElement.resourceId).calendarColumnDiv;
                        var columnItemDiv = jQuery("<div>", {
                            "class": "kalender-calendarContainer-calendarColumnItem"
                        }).append("empty");
                        column.append(columnItemDiv);
                    }

                }

            }
```

This prints like wiev above. 
Btw, i don't have much programming background so i don't know much what i am doing actually. 
Thanks.

Comment: "I have a problem with creating a view" - Please describe in more detail what the issue is. What is happening now, vs What you want to happen instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to merge 3 different arrays into one array. Easiest would be to merge the details of an event with the data:

```
const dataWithResourceDetail = dataArray.map((item) => ({
  name: resourceArray.find(
    (r) => (r.resourceId = item.resourceId),
  ).name,
  title: item.title,
  start: item.start,
  end: item.end,
}));
```

That assumes that every resourceId in dataArray can be found in resourceArray (if not you need to set a default for it).

Then take the dates array and map it to objects that contain resources where start and end of that resource fall within that date.

Full Code:

```js
const resourceArray = [{"resourceId":"a","name":"Test User"},{"resourceId":"b","name":"Test User2"},{"resourceId":"c","name":"Test User3"},{"resourceId":"d","name":"Test User4"},{"resourceId":"e","name":"Test User5"},{"resourceId":"f","name":"Test User6"}];
const dataArray = [{"id":"1","resourceId":"a","start":"2018-10-02","end":"2018-10-17","title":"event 1"},{"id":"2","resourceId":"b","start":"2018-10-07","end":"2018-10-07","title":"event 2"},{"id":"3","resourceId":"c","start":"2018-10-06","end":"2018-10-15","title":"event 3"},{"id":"4","resourceId":"d","start":"2018-10-07","end":"2018-10-21","title":"event 4"},{"id":"5","resourceId":"e","start":"2018-10-07","end":"2018-10-22","title":"event 5"},{"id":"6","resourceId":"f","start":"2018-10-07","end":"2018-10-10","title":"event 6"},{"id":"7","resourceId":"f","start":"2018-10-11","end":"2018-10-13","title":"event 7"}];
const dates = ['2018-10-21']

const dataWithResourceDetail = dataArray.map((item) => ({
  name: resourceArray.find(
    (r) => (r.resourceId = item.resourceId),
  ).name,
  title: item.title,
  start: item.start,
  end: item.end,
}));
const datesWithResources = dates.map((date) => ({
  date,
  resources: dataWithResourceDetail.filter(
    (item) =>
      item.start.localeCompare(date) < 1 &&
      item.end.localeCompare(date) > -1,
  ),
}));
console.log('dates with events:', datesWithResources);
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand exactly. But is here what you want?)

```js
var resourceArray =[ {resourceId:"a", "name":"Test User"},
                { resourceId:"b", "name":"Test User2"},
                { resourceId:"c", "name":"Test User3"},
                { resourceId:"d", "name":"Test User4"},
                { resourceId:"e", "name":"Test User5"},
                { resourceId:"f", "name":"Test User6"}];
                
var dataArray= [
      { "id": "1", "resourceId": "a", "start": "2018-10-02", "end": "2018-10-17", "title": "event 1" },
      { "id": "2", "resourceId": "b", "start": "2018-10-07", "end": "2018-10-07", "title": "event 2" },
      { "id": "3", "resourceId": "c", "start": "2018-10-06", "end": "2018-10-15", "title": "event 3" },
      { "id": "4", "resourceId": "d", "start": "2018-10-07", "end": "2018-10-21", "title": "event 4" },
      { "id": "5", "resourceId": "e", "start": "2018-10-07", "end": "2018-10-22", "title": "event 5" },
      { "id": "6", "resourceId": "f", "start": "2018-10-07", "end": "2018-10-10", "title": "event 6" },
      { "id": "7", "resourceId": "f", "start": "2018-10-11", "end": "2018-10-13", "title": "event 7" }
    ];
    
var dates=["2018/10/05", "2018/10/07", "2018/10/10", "2018/10/15"];

var rows = [];
for(var i=0; i < dates.length; i++) {

  var date = new Date(dates[i]);
  
  var events = dataArray.filter(function(x) {
    var startDate = new Date(x.start);
    var endDate = new Date(x.end);
    return startDate <= date && date <= endDate;
  });

  var innerRows = events.map(function(x) {
    var resource = resourceArray.filter(function(y) {
      return y.resourceId === x.resourceId;
    })[0];
    
    if(!resource) {
     return null;
    }
    
    return {
      name: resource.name,
      title: x.title
    }
  }).filter(function(y) {
    return y;
  });
  
  rows.push({date: dates[i], rows: innerRows});
}

var table = createEl('table', document.body);
var thead = createEl('thead', table);
var theadrow = createEl('tr', thead);
createEl('th', theadrow, 'Date');

for(var i=0; i<resourceArray.length; i++) {
  var th = createEl('th', theadrow, resourceArray[i].name);
}

var tbody = createEl('tbody', table);

for(var i=0; i<rows.length; i++) {
  var tbodyrow = createEl('tr', tbody);
  createEl('td', tbodyrow, rows[i].date); 
  for(var j=0; j<resourceArray.length; j++) {
    var row = rows[i].rows.filter(function(x) { 
      return x.name === resourceArray[j].name; 
    })[0];
    createEl('td', tbodyrow, row ? row.title : '');
  }
}


function createEl(el, parent, text) {
  var d=document.createElement(el);
  if(text) {
    d.innerHTML = text;
  }
  parent.appendChild(d);
  return d;
}
```

```css
table, table th, table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Yep. Sorry my lack of english is the problem actually. I'd like to have this view, but 
display rest of the dates and show events as a block if they occurs on multiple days. Bless you.